# How does electron hole recombination cause a base current in a transistor?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electric-current, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

Can anyone help me in understanding the idea behind the recombination current? If a recombination takes place, then how does it lead to a current as in the base-emitter junction of a transistor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Physics SE! 
Your question:
It does because new electrons and holes are provided by the circuit taking the place of the recombined ones .

So there is a motion of electrons to the right and a motion of holes to the left.

Because these motions have opposite directions , a net current exists.

Answer (score -1):

Recombination means that electrons will go from the higher energy state  (conduction band) to the lower energy states (valence band) and then electrons will travel from valence to valence shell/band from atom to atom.

Conduction from valence to valence shell is different from the conduction in conduction band/shell as conduction in conduction band is because of the free electrons while in recombination, electrons from conduction band dip into valence band and recombines with atom and then they travel from atom to atom.

In normal conductors  like copper etc, conduction occurs just in the conduction band. While in semi conductors we have also valence conduction besides the normal conduction.